# How to create a one-hot tensor for k largest elements in 4d tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Given a tensor of shape lets say (2,3,3,1) where batch size is 2 and each matrix is of shape (3,3,1). How can you find k largest elements from each matrix and create a one-hot matrix such that entries at those k locations is 1 and 0 elsewhere. 
Example:(Note each entry will be a floating point number for simplicity integers are used)

```
input_tensor=[[[1, 5, 7],
      [2, 8, 1],
      [3, 9, 1],
     ],
     [[0, 9, 5],
      [6, 0, 4],
      [3, 0, 8]
     ]
    ]
```

One-hot tensor for k=3:

```
output_tensor=[[[0, 0, 1],
      [0, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 0],
     ],
     [[0, 1, 0],
      [1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1]
     ]
    ]
```

tf.nn.top_k will return k largest elements only from the last dimension. How to get k largest elements from a 3d tensor ex:(3,3,1).
Also tf.one_hot will put a one in each row for the specified depth and given indices which is not the case here.

Comment: the `input_tensor` you have shown in the example is of size (2X3X3) can you correct your example or your problem description what ever is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the `k` largest elements from each matrix, you can use the following method.

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_tensor = tf.constant([[[1, 5, 7],[2, 8, 1],[3, 9, 1]],
                            [[0, 9, 5],[6, 0, 4],[3, 0, 8]]],dtype=tf.int32)

k_tf = tf.placeholder(shape=(),dtype=tf.int32)

temp = tf.reshape(input_tensor,shape=(input_tensor.shape[0],-1))
# [[1 5 7 2 8 1 3 9 1]
#  [0 9 5 6 0 4 3 0 8]]
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(indices=tf.nn.top_k(temp,k=k_tf)[1], depth=temp.shape[1]), axis=1)
# [[0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
result = tf.reshape(result,input_tensor.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('k=2:')
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={k_tf: 2}))
    print('k=3:')
    print(sess.run(result,feed_dict={k_tf:3}))

k=2:
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]]
k=3:
[[[0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example, which is actially of shape 2,3,3

```
output = tf.one_hot(tf.math.argmax(inp, 2), 3)
```

So first we take the index of largest entry in desired axis, 2 in this case. An then apply one hot encoding with desired depth, 3

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

inputs=np.array([[[1, 5, 7],
      [2, 8, 1],
      [3, 9, 1],
     ],
     [[0, 9, 5],
      [6, 0, 4],
      [3, 0, 8]
     ]
    ])

j = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(2,3,3))    
_, inds = tf.nn.top_k(input_tensor, 3)    
r = tf.reshape(inds[:,:,3-j], [-1])
encoded_tensor = tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(r, 3),tf.shape(input_tensor))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for k in [1,2,3]:
        print ("K:",k)
        print (sess.run(encoded_tensor , feed_dict={j: k, input_tensor: inputs}))
```

Output:

```
K: 1
[[[1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]

 [[1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]]]
K: 2
[[[0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 1.]
  [1. 0. 0.]]]
K: 3
[[[0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]]
```

- Use `top_k` to get all the indices in the order
- Pick the required indices based on the value of `k`
- Flatten and create a one-hot encoding of level 3 (since the columns in the matrix is 3)
- Reshape to the shape of input_tensor.

Comment: I think the OP meant to find top `k` elements out of elements of 2 dimensional matrix `(3x3)`